# Gradle doesn't refresh dependencies in Idea project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I've created gradle project in Idea Intellij and tried to work with gradle via command line. After calling `gradle --refresh-dependencies` or `gradle --refresh-dependencies build` I can't see loaded dependencies in Idea. After calling `gradle dependencies` command I can see my libs in command line, but not in Idea project.
I've read many articles on this and other sites, but I can't fix the problem.
Here my build.gradle file:
[image]

Maybe I need use gradle wrapper? Of course I can work with gradle via Idea editor, but I want to work via command line.
Thanks!

Comment: actions via command line and via IDE are different things, try to refresh gradle project in Idea to see  changes there.

Comment: Check [the logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).

Comment: Russiancold, explaine, please, in details you message "actions via command line and via IDE are different things". Via Idea all works fine

Comment: CrazyCoder, thanks! I'll try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case your actions via command line doesn't affect Idea, it needs to refactor project itself to show changes. Other example: you can simply open some java classes in Idea but whatever you do externally Idea won't recognize them as a project till creating some configs. So, in a nutshell: `gradle build` may work propely but the only way to see any changes in Idea is to refresh gradle project there.

Comment: Can someone provide instructions for how to "refresh gradle project" in Idea? It's not immediately apparent to a new user how to do that.

Comment: @trevorsky Open the gradle tool window and click on the circulating arrows symbol (first symbol from the left inside the top toolbar)

Comment: Where is the gradle tool window?

Comment: I didn't find this "Gradle tool window", but when pressing 'shift-shift' and searching "gradle" I spotted an action called 'Sync project with Gradle files' which seems to do the trick.